# Error stream_wrapper_unregister() when installing magento

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I wanted to try `magento CE edition` so I downloaded it uploaded all the files to my host but then I get this error when i visit the url.

> Warning: stream_wrapper_unregister(): Unable to unregister protocol
>   phar:// in
>   /customers/d/f/0/(my_website_url)l/httpd.www/magento/app/bootstrap.php
>   on line 11

**What am I doing wrong?**